# Finding a paired values from the row throughout the dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to polishing my R skills and sort of hit my limit.

The issue I am trying to find the solution as follows.
Suppose my dataframe is as below ,

```
n = c(2, 15, 31 , 33) 
n2 = c( 10 , 9, 10 , 40) 
n3 = c( 11 , 10 , 11 , 42) 
df = data.frame(n , n2 , n3)



> df
  n n2 n3
1  2 10 11
2 15  9 10
3 31 10 11
4 33 40 42
```

if I would like to go through each row , and generate a random pair :eg 2,10 and go through each of the rest of the rows to find a repeated pair and print out the common pairs and number of occurrence , how can I do that?

In the above example , the only pair that repeat is 10 and 11 at rows 1 and 3.

So far I have thought about the pseudo code as follows

```
for(each row in the dataframe)
{
  for (each of the values in the row)
   { 
     for every pair
   }
  find a repeated pair
  if found store in a dataframe
}
```

and to find the random pair using **combn** function.

But I am a little lost at the part on iteration through out the dataframe rows.
Pls help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your description, you seem to say that you want one random pair per row, but in your sudo code you have `for (each of the values in the row)`, suggesting you want a pair for every value in every row. And do you really just want to `print` the results, or do you want to store them?

Comment: `combn` would be useful for finding every possible pair. I would recommend sampling column numbers, `sample(1:ncol(dataframe), size = 2)` will give you a random pair of columns.

Comment: @Gregor : Yes. Store them in an another dataframe. It would be better than to just print it. Thanks for the suggestion! Updated my pseudo code to store instead of print.

Comment: @Gregor : but for the pair , I really would like to go through every possible combinations , not just random. Or perhaps my understanding fails there.

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest editing your question to reflect that. You say *"generate a random pair*", but you in comments it sounds like you mean "for every possible pair".

Comment: @Gregor : Thanks for spotting the error. Have updated the question as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Instead of thinking about selecting every combination of two *values* for each row, we'll get every combination of two *column numbers* - which will be the same for every row. Then we use `plyr::count` as a convenience function to count rows with the same values for an entire data frame at once. This way we can loop over the combinations of column indices rather than over rows. I use `apply`, but you could write it as a for loop instead.

```
pairs = combn(ncol(df), m = 2)
result = apply(pairs, MAR = 2, FUN = function(p) {
  plyr::count(df[p])
})
names(result) = apply(pairs, MAR = 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "_")
```

The result is a `list` where each item is is a data frame with two columns and a `freq` column giving the number of rows in the original data each value-pair occurred.

```
result
# $`1_2`
#    n n2 freq
# 1  2 10    1
# 2 15  9    1
# 3 31 10    1
# 4 33 40    1
# 
# $`1_3`
#    n n3 freq
# 1  2 11    1
# 2 15 10    1
# 3 31 11    1
# 4 33 42    1
# 
# $`2_3`
#   n2 n3 freq
# 1  9 10    1
# 2 10 11    2
# 3 40 42    1
```

If you want to omit the values that aren't repeated, we can just subset them out:

```
lapply(result, subset, freq > 1)
# $`1_2`
# [1] n    n2   freq
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $`1_3`
# [1] n    n3   freq
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $`2_3`
#   n2 n3 freq
# 2 10 11    2
```

Comment: Nice! Yes. I can see that 10 and 11 repeated for column 2 and 3 twice! Thanks!

Comment: Oh and thanks for the explanation of the code as well. That is more important than just throwing me the code itself.

Comment: Oh and those who would like to export 1 set of list to csv  , here is the code.. capture.output(result$'1_2', file = 'C:/test.csv')

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different method

```
n = c(2, 15, 31 , 15) # changed the dataset to have some common pairs in n and n2 too
n2 = c( 10 , 9, 10 , 9) 
n3 = c( 11 , 10 , 11 , 42) 
df = data.frame(n , n2 , n3)

library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(utils)

cols<-colnames(df) # define the columns that you want to do the pair checking for

combinations<- as.data.frame(combn(cols,2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# picks up all combinations of columns


#iterates over each pair of columns
 all_combs<- lapply(names(combinations[cols1]), function(x){
    df %>%
      group_by(!! sym( combinations[[x]][1]),!! sym( combinations[[x]][2])) %>%
      filter(n()>1) # groups by the two columns, and filters out pairs that occur more than once. You can add a distinct command below if you 
#dont want them repeated


  })
 all_combs_df <- do.call("rbind", all_combs)# all_combs is in a list format, use rbind to convert into a dataframe
 all_combs_df
```

the output is this

```
      n    n2    n3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   15.    9.   10.
2   15.    9.   42.
3    2.   10.   11.
4   31.   10.   11.
```